# What parts of given/when are experimental?

Tags: perl, syntax, switch-statement

Has the entire "switch" feature become experimental? Are there parts of it I can rely on using without future versions of Perl breaking my code? In general, what is the policy toward changing stable features to experimental?

### Background

`use feature "switch"` has been in Perl since 5.10. From 5.10 to 5.14, `perlsyn` seems to indicate that this is a stable, supported feature.

Starting with 5.16, however, `perlsyn` [begins to call it](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.16.2/perlsyn.html#Switch-Statements) "an *experimental* switch feature" and gets a lot more confusing about what's considered experimental.

Parts of the documentation seem to indicate *everything* about the feature is experimental:

> Under the "switch" feature, Perl gains the experimental keywords `given`, `when`, `default`, `continue`, and `break`.

There's even an entire section about the [Experimental Details on given and when](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Experimental-Details-on-given-and-when).

However, `perlsyn` *also* says that "The `foreach` is the non-experimental way to set a topicalizer" and gives an example that seems to imply that foreach/when is not experimental.

As far as I can tell, the "experimental" language came from [commit c2f1e22](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/commit/c2f1e229171d1aa65dacd9b3bb09f4298de8fba7) which references [RT #90926](https://rt.perl.org/rt3/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=90926) which still doesn't give much context, even when paired with [RT# 90906](https://rt.perl.org/rt3/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=90906).

Answer (score 5):

> Has the entire "switch" feature become experimental?

No. It has always been.

Upd: Oh wow, maybe I'm wrong. I can't find a mention of that in 5.10.0 or .1. Maybe it wasn't? Or maybe they forgot to note it? Either way, it seems they messed up worse than I thought if so! But based on what I've seen since, I think the lesson was learned. (e.g. I still think `values $ref` is a bad idea, but at least it was marked experimental from day 
1.)

> Are there parts of it I can rely on using without future versions of Perl breaking my code?

Technically, no, although the devs are always careful when it comes to backwards compatibility.

> In general, what is the policy toward changing stable features to experimental?

I don't see that ever happening. The deprecation process would be used instead.

---

Changes so far:

- `given` is changing from creating a lexical `$_` to localising `$_` like foreach loops in 5.18 (or did it already happen in 5.16?).
- 5.10.1 saw some big changes in smart-matching*. Don't use (smart-matching in) 5.10.0.

Possible future changes:

- The behaviour of smart-matching* is still a hot topic.

* — True, this is a feature distinct from given-when, but it's the same or closely related in most people's minds.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. Was it simply a documentation bug that perlsyn from 5.10 to 5.14 never called the feature experimental?

Comment: Note the update I made under my answer to the first question. I guess I spoke too soon

Comment: "Maybe it wasn't? Or maybe they forgot to note it?" Right, hence my question. :)

Comment: Yeah, like I said, spoke too soon. But I did go on to explain this is not suppose to happen.